# how to get info of user when they login via Facebook using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I write this code. If the user has logged in before, it works properly but if the user hasn't logged into the Facebook, he will be redirected to Facebook login page and after successful login, he redirected to the page that I've provided before in developers.facebook.com/app. In this case I can't get user info. Below is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var client_id = my_client_id;
        var url       = 'http://localhost/myitems.html';
        var scope     = 'email,public_profile';

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : client_id,
                xfbml      : true,
                status     : true,
                version    : 'v2.5'
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        function loginFacebook(){
            FB.getLoginStatus(handleLoginFacebook);
        }

        function handleLoginFacebook(res){
            if(res.status==='connected'){
                var user={};
                user.access_token=res.authResponse.accessToken;

                FB.api('/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,picture',function(res){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(res));
                    user.first_name   = res.first_name;
                    user.last_name    = res.last_name;
                    user.network      = 'facebook';
                    user.image        = res.picture;
                    user.network_id   = res.id;
                    user.deviceToken  = 0;
                    user.email        = res.email;
                    loginSocial(user, function(data){
                        var d=JSON.stringify(data);
                        alert(d);
                        d=JSON.parse(d);

                        if(d.success==true){
                            store(d);
                            window.location='myitems.html';
                        }else{
                            window.location='index.html';
                        }
                    });
                });
            }else{
                window.location='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id='+client_id+'&redirect_uri='+url+'&scope='+scope;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <button onclick='loginFacebook()'>Facebook Login</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else should be something like:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
   //Get date here from the response.authResponse
   //In 'scope:' declare the scope of information you need
}, {scope: 'email, public_profile, user_friends', return_scopes: true});
```

Comment: Nikolay, I want to redirect to Facebook login page instead of popup window. let me clear it. I have a button when user click on it, they are redirected to Facebook login page. after successful login in Facebook, then redirected to my page and now that's what I need, means the current user